# Getting everything in bootstrap container to stay a fixed width

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap container with a bunch of form data in it. I think the width of the container is 970px regardless of how wide my window is. But when I size my window down to a much smaller size the form data inside gets pushed around and moved. Is there a way to keep the containers data all set a fixed width so the elements inside don't shift around when I resize the window?

I tried settign the min-width but that didn't do anything.

```
.container {
    min-width: 970px !important;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Comment: If you're referring to the the responsive nature of the bootstrap, you'd be defeating the purpose of using a responsive framework by overriding it.

Comment: yes I understand, I want the responsive nature for all the pages except one. So I'm trying to override it on this page.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using columns inside the container, don't forget they have a percentage width, so you'll need to fix width those elements.

I can't be for sure without seeing your code, so perhaps post a JSFiddle and I'll edit this with a proper answer.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using fix min-width? It is the reason form data moved. Try to use `col-md-4` or `col-xs-5` etc classes or percentage width.

Comment: inside my container I have  a bootstrap row and two bootstrap columns that have col-*-* classes, can you provide me with further information to set these columns so that they don't shift around? Do I need to set all the classes (ex. col-lg, col-md, col-sm, col-xs)?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what are you trying to achieve as it seems like you are going against the responsive framework, which makes me wonder why you use bootstrap at the first place?

Besides, I think this meta tag post will help you achieve such a thing by using `meta` tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=970">
```

and you should change `.container` to `.container-fluid`.

Answer (score 0):

All information needed is here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#disable-responsive

And here's an example of how it works: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/non-responsive/